# vba Macro doesn't wait until workbook finishes downloading from SAP

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have a macro that downloads a report from SAP ABAP-based software, that opens automatically and then starts working on said Excel file.

The problem is that the file is a bit heavy and takes a few seconds to open, so I need the code to wait until the file is open.

Edit: I updated the code, but still have the same issue:

```
Sub WorkbookHandling()

Do While wbZus Is Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbZus = Workbooks("MacroToolBoxDummy.xlsx")
    Set wsZus = wbZus.Worksheets(1)
    DoEvents
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop

On Error Resume Next
    wsZus.Rows(1).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    wsZus.Columns("A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1
On Error GoTo 0
 
    wsZus.Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
```

How can I give a few seconds to the Excel to open? Or what kind of condition I can use so the code doesn't continue until it's true?

Thanks!!

Comment: If the workbook you need was not open, `Set wbZus = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)` will refer the existing last opened workbook... Nothing will be changed in the following loop. Try `Set wbZus = Workbooks.Open("abc.xlsx full path")`. Excel will naturally wait until the workbook is open and you can do what you need to do.

Comment: Does the SAP workbook open in the same instance of excel as your macro, or in a new Excel instance?

Comment: If I understood well, I think it's important to tell people that your Excel macro runs a script (SAP GUI Scripting) to automate user actions on screens of the SAP software, the last automated user action being the asynchronous creation and opening of an Excel file.

Comment: I do not think it is any connection between the code behavior and the workbook origin (coming from SAP). Your code is wrong (setting the necessary workbook like being the last and then waiting for Excel to change it...). Did you try my above suggestion?

Comment: @FaneDuru would that work even if SAP opens the workbook automatically?

Comment: @clchi: I do not understand how SAP opens the workbook automatically and your code is able to wait for that, like it is... In such a case,  I would propose a timer (a module simple timer, using API) which will look for a specific workbook and define workbook `Public` variable. Let us say `Private SAPWb as Workbook`. When this one is not Nothing, the timer calls your sub and kills itself. But, **do you know the workbook open by SAP name**? Or, does this workbook have some characteristics to be checked by the timer called function? Some specific headers, values etc.

Comment: @clchi: If you are able to give me some characteristics to be looked for, to be specific only to that SAP open Workbook, I will try helping you with such a timer and a function to check what is to be checked... But, is it a logic based on what to know when SAP will open that workbook? Will it be open when SAP is in good mood? :)

Comment: @FaneDuru what the macro does is load an SAP transaction that has a table, it selects the excel spreadsheet export option, I select the file name and path, and depending on the amount of data, it can take a few seconds to open the file. (I can't stop SAP from opening the workbook)

Then it'll call the Sub I posted originally and work on said WB. When I'm downloading less than 20 lines, it'll open directly and will do these actions with no prob. The issue is when the table is bigger, because it takes more than 5 sec to open, so it crashes since it doesn't find the excel file to work on.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))`

Add this above the code that opens your excel. Estimate the wait time. So if it takes 30 seconds, change the 10 to 30